# How to increment the font size of the Xcode UI?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode

I googled and saw only how to increment the editor font size (code size).

But how do I enlarge the UI font size?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18930077/6557621

Comment: @MCCCS No, that is about how to change the editor font size, not the UI such as the project navigator or other parts of the Xcode. I think Apple really is unthoughtful in font size. Not only Xcode, other applications such as the App Store do not have font size settings, making it really difficult to read app reviews in tiny fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is system-wide question, rather than Xcode one. What *is* under Xcode control is editor font size.

But what you are asking is to change system fonts that are being used for Xcode main menu, files treeView, etc.

As far as I know, zoom under accessibility is only available option in this case.

"Apple main menu" > "System Preferences..." > "Accessibility" > "Zoom"

Answer (score 31):

Starting with Xcode 12 you can also adjust the Navigator font size inside the Settings panel (Preferences in older versions):

```
Xcode -> Settings -> General -> Navigator Size
```

By default, it matches the system font scale, but you can override the settings and choose one of three different options: "Small", "Medium" or "Large".

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to set a custom size, for me "Large" is not big enough. Using a 4K display the file names are still tiny.

Comment: I set it to "Large", and I don't think it even changed :(

Comment: If the Large settings isn't large enough for you, maybe you should try a different resolution for your display, or change the "Scaling" option (if it is available for your display)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/hidpi-mode-os-x/

It took me a while to find this but I didn't give up because I felt my eyes were being strained too much!

How to Enable HiDPI Mode in Mac OS X

- copy this into terminal
- sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
- Next, reboot your Mac and, upon logging back in, head to System Preferences > Displays.

Here, you’ll see the familiar preference window where you can set your resolution and refresh rate. Most users will likely have the “Default for Display” option checked, which is typically your display’s native resolution. Click Scaled to reveal additional resolutions and you’ll see one or more options at the bottom of the list with “(HiDPI)” appended to their resolutions. Click on one of the HiDPI modes to enable it on your desired display.

Note: If you’re not seeing the HiDPI resolutions listed in System Preferences after using the Terminal command above, try clicking on the “Scaled” radio button while holding the Alt/Option key on your keyboard. This trick reveals additional resolutions for all displays, and should list the HiDPI resolutions if they weren’t already visible.